# How to change XdmNode base URI in S9API

Tags: saxon, s9api

I have a home grown cache for Saxon's S9API `XdmNode` instances, implementing `get`, `put`, `move`, and `remove` operations by URI. The `move` operation allows moving a `XdmNode` from one URI to another.

My problem is that the `XdmNode` internally retains the base URI of the document. How do I update the base URI of the underlaying `NodeInfo`? When the underlaying node is a `DOMNodeWrapper`, the base URI can be updated. But for example `TinyDocumentImpl` is immutable.

Is there a solution that allows updating the base URI of `TinyDocumentImpl` that *doesn't* involve building a new document by making a full copy of the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this question when it first appeared because of the lack of a "saxon" tag.

One option is to use the `LinkedTree` as your chosen tree model; linked trees are mutable and the `DocumentImpl` class has a `setBaseURI()` method. You can choose the tree model using `DocumentBuilder.setTreeModel()`. (But use this with care; if you change properties of a node in the middle of a transformation, the consequences are unpredictable.)

Another option is to wrap a `TreeInfo` in a `net.sf.saxon.tree.wrapper.RebasedDocument`, which creates a virtual copy of the original node, identical except for having a different base URI. The virtual copy carries almost zero memory cost, but there is a small overhead when navigating the tree.